# Cardinality of product of subsets of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, products

Let $A, B$ be finite subsets of a group $G$ (not necessarily finite). Is it true that $|AB| = |BA|$? More generally, is it true that $|ABC| = |ABC| =\cdots$ any permutation of three elements, if $C$ is another finite subset of $G$?

For the first question, I know this to be true by the product formula when $A$ and $B$ are groups (so we not only have equality but a formula even), but I was wondering if this was true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I just chose two sets each consisting of three random elements of $S_4$.

$A = \{(1,4,3,2),(1,4,2),(1,4,3)\}$ and $B = \{(1,4,2,3),(1,3),(1,3,4)\}$

and found that $|AB|=9$ and $|BA|=8$.

Answer (score 1):

In $S_3$, let
\begin{align*}
A&=\{(1\;2),(1\;2\;3)\}\\[4pt]
B&=\{(2\;3),(1\;2\;3)\}
\end{align*}
Then $AB$ has $4$ elements, while $BA$ has $2$ elements.